# access viewModel function in javascript function- knockout

Tags: knockout.js

Have a problem accessing methods defined inside view model.

Below are the view model definitions:

```
ProductMenu = function (name, subProductsMenu1, selectedMenu) {
    name = ko.observable(name);
    submenu = ko.observableArray(subProductsMenu1);
    selectedProductName = ko.observable();
};
ProductSubMenu = function () {
    submenuName = ko.observable();
    submenu2 = ko.observableArray([]);
    selectedSubMenuName = ko.observable();
};
ProductSubMenu2 = function () {
    submenu2Name = ko.observable();
    properties = ko.observableArray([]);
    selectedSubMenu2Name = ko.observable();
};
Properties = function () {
    productName = ko.observable();
    shortDesc = ko.observable();
    longDesc = ko.observable();
    additionalDocs = ko.observableArray([]);
};
var MainViewModel = function () {
    productModel = new ProductMenu();
    subMenuModel = new ProductSubMenu();
    submenu2Model = new ProductSubMenu2();
    propertyModel = new Properties();
    AllProductsModel = ko.observableArray([]);

   ReturnToFamilyProduct = ko.observable(true);
    ShowSubMenu = ko.observable(false);
    showSubMenu2 = ko.observable(false);
    ShowBackBtnOnSubMenuClick = ko.observable(false);
    IfDocumentsPresent = ko.observable(true);

    //to add product to products array
    AddProducts = function (name, subProductsMenu1, selectedMenu) {
        this.AllProductsModel.push(new ProductMenu(name, subProductsMenu1, selectedMenu));
    };
};
```

In $(document).ready function i am trying to access the view model methods, the code is shown below:

```
 var VM;

    $(document).ready(function () {
        VM = new MainViewModel();
        ko.applyBindings(VM);

        FetchProductFamiliesForProductsKO();
    });
    function FetchProductFamiliesForProductsKO() {

        $.getJSON(GetPath('/FetchProduct'), {}, function (data) {
            for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i = i + 1) {
                var family = data[i];
                VM.AddProducts(family, null, family);
            }
        }).error(function () {
            console.log("Error occured");
        });enter code here
    };
```

I get an error in the function "FetchProductFamiliesForProductsKO" : uncaught typeerror: object[object object] has no method 'AddProducts'.

How to access the MainViewModel methods? are the View model definitions correct?  and how to intialize the MainViewModel?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem here is in the way you are defining your `ViewModel`. You are defining properties and functions without attaching them the instance of the created object that's why `JS` don't see the function `AddProducts`.

you should define your `ViewModel` like this:

```
function MainViewModel() {
    self = this;
    self.productModel = new ProductMenu();
    self.subMenuModel = new ProductSubMenu();
    self.submenu2Model = new ProductSubMenu2();
    self.propertyModel = new Properties();
    self.AllProductsModel = ko.observableArray([]);

    self.ReturnToFamilyProduct = ko.observable(true);
    self.ShowSubMenu = ko.observable(false);
    self.showSubMenu2 = ko.observable(false);
    self.ShowBackBtnOnSubMenuClick = ko.observable(false);
    self.IfDocumentsPresent = ko.observable(true);

    //to add product to products array
    self.AddProducts = function (name, subProductsMenu1, selectedMenu) {
        self.AllProductsModel.push(new ProductMenu(name, subProductsMenu1, selectedMenu));
    };
}
```

notice variable `self` that refer to the instance of your created object

kindly check this demo and watch the console without errors **[jsfiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Ebram/hX9Bg/)**