# binding the viewmodel to view- knockout

Tags: knockout.js

I had posted a question about viewmodel in this link: [access viewModel function in javascript function- knockout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16959798/access-viewmodel-function-in-javascript-function-knockout)

I have problem binding the same view model to View. Below is the View code:

```
 <div id="familyDiv">
   <ul id="productFamilyList" data-bind="foreach: VM.AllProductsModel">
       <li data-bind="text: name">
           <a data-bind="text: name">
           </a>
       </li>
     </ul>
</div>
```

The list is not getting displayed. Any changes to be made in the view?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please post your viewmodel

Answer (score 0):

You should not specify name of your root viewmodel. Use `AllProductsModel` instead of `VM.AllProductsModel`:

```
<div id="familyDiv">
   <ul id="productFamilyList" data-bind="foreach: AllProductsModel">
       <li data-bind="text: name">
           <a data-bind="text: name">
           </a>
       </li>
     </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: thanks for the reply. I did give just the element name- AllProductsModel. It is not working. Any other solution?

Comment: Could you post your vievmodel?

Answer (score 0):

You have to construct your model bit further

```
ProductMenu = function (name, subProductsMenu1, selectedMenu) {
    this.name = ko.observable(name);
    this.submenu = ko.observableArray(subProductsMenu1);
    this.selectedProductName = ko.observable();
```

};

please see the working fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/aroor/hX9Bg/2/